# Convert .dwg file into .dwf file using Teigha tool

Tags: file-formats, dwg

I am using teigha tool to convert my dwg file into dwf file. Can anybody help to explain the procudure for the same.

Your prompt reply will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since access to the documentation at ODA (http://www.opendesign.com/) is closed to non-members, it may be difficult for us to provide you with this help unless someone else here is a member of ODA.

Comment: if this is a small-one-time need. I could help you out by using my autodesk products to create dwf file.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.opendesign.com/teigha_file_converter

[image]

But DWF is only available from AutoCAD

[image]

Comment: @mapperz- a dxf is different than a dwf. dxf = drawing transfer format - while dwf = drawing web format. If I am not mistaken, a dwf can be printed from within the autodesk free software "truview" - similar to printing to pdf it is a type of output device from within autocad and other autodesk products. I think trueview will plot to dwf.

Comment: Correct - added an image from AutoCAD - If need to Print from DWF - wouldn't exporting to PDF be much easier - the question then is what advantage DWF has over PDF?

Comment: it started about 10-12 years ago as the autodesk answer to pdf. pdf took of and dwf stayed home. it is a good format. especially if you need lightweight vewable interactive cad files. advantage is you can save views/layouts, and turn on off layers. even fly 3d.

Comment: Thanks! I have to write a code for this conversion using autocad teigha functions.

Answer (score 2):

AutoDWG [DWG2DWF](http://autodwg.com/DWG_DWF_Converter/) Converter a batch converter converts DWG/DXF to DWF without need of AutoCAD.

Select a project (folder), and generate a dwf file for each dwg file in the project, then publish them to the Internet/Intranet or the drawing management system.

The command line will allow you to convert dwg to dwf in silent without interface.

Answer (score 1):

for some free gui solutions to this problem...
You can download impression (semi cheap) or free student version which has saveas > dwf
[Impression](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=9246650&siteID=123112http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=9246650&siteID=123112)
Or to create/print dwf from dwg layout download
[Trueview](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=16979981)
And then to view dwf you can use an extensive autodesk api or the gui download
[Design Review](http://usa.autodesk.com/design-review/)